# Where actually is GAC files located?

Tags: .net

There is something i don't understand about the `GAC`files location ...

When i install some assembly in the `GAC` - where will be actually the assembly location ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377551/physicalinstalled-path-of-dll-installed-to-the-gac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `%WINDIR%\Assembly`

P.S. The best way to look at this folder is with Windows Explorer, because custom file managers may show unneeded technical folders etc.

Comment: this path is where can i see all the assembly version - but actually where is the files physical located ? ?

Answer (score 1):

The assembly cache is usually stored in `%windir%\assembly`.

Answer (score 1):

They are in

> %windir%\Assembly

which is displayed via a shell extension in explorer.

If you want to see the underlying physical files map a drive to the location eg.

> \%compname%\c$\Windows\assembly

and you'll get the full view.