# Installing a (sort-of) weakly-named .dll to the GAC

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, gac, gacutil

I need to migrate some programs from one server to another. In the process, I found that we were missing a .dll - I tracked it down on the original server. It was both on the file system (in what seems to be a storage directory, not linked to anything) and the GAC. I took the .dll from the storage directory on to the new server, and tried to install it using the GACUtil - but it failed with the message:

`Failure adding assembly to cache: Attempt to install an assembly without a strong name`

This seems strange to me as clearly it has been installed successfully on the previous server (the version #s of the two .dlls are the same). However, as I do not have the source code for this .dll, it is possible that the version in the GAC was re-compiled as strongly named, and the version in "storage" was not updated.

One possible work-around is to install the .dll manually. In C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\assembly\ lives the .NET 4.0 separated GAC directory structure, into which I could create a GAC_MSIL\[.dllname]\v###__[PublicKey]\ folder, using the same public key as the GAC implementation on the old server, and put the .dll file in there. However, the .dll was definitely not compiled with .NET 4.0 (or even .NET 3.5, I don't think) - so would this even work? Or what changes would I have to make to get it to work?

I don't know how to manually install something into the "old" GAC, the one with the windows explorer GUI, as the directory structure is not exposed to me. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/382318/1675729) seems to indicate that there is an underlying structure into which I could attempt a similar method of manual installation - if this will work, can someone give me some more information about how to access that structure?

Of course, if there is a way to install a weakly-named .dll into the GAC, that would be ideal. This .dll is not going to cause any .dll-hell problems, as it has a specific purpose (and name), and will only be used by one program. I don't know how to do this, however, and since it seems completely opposed to the purpose of the GAC, I'm not surprised that there's a lack of information about it.

I'm open to any and all suggestions, and will happily provide any more information that I can - I'm unsure of what's important to note here.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Calling this "ideal" is perhaps representative for the kind of practices that got you into this mess.  If you don't have the source code then it is very unlikely that you could reliably tell that this DLL was strong-named before.  You'll have to stop the bleeding by *uninstalling* that DLL from the GAC.

Comment: It is impressive how quickly your standards for code management fall when you're dealing with inherited legacy enterprise code. That said, I ended up tracking down the original code and re-compiling it as a strongly-typed .dll.